# remove_menu_page() not getting initialized within if condition

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to remove some menu pages based on user role, but when I add the function inside the `if condition` it doesn't do anything.

```
function contributor_posts_action() {
  if ($role == 'contributor_posts') { // contributor_posts - custom role
    // echo  'here'; for testing purposes and WORKS, so it goes under the if condition
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus_contrib' );
    function remove_menus_contrib(){
        remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );    
        remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                   
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=directory' );          
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=city' );
    } // this function doesn't get hooked

    add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_admin_bar_items', 999 );
    function remove_admin_bar_items( $wp_admin_bar ) {
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-directory' );
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-city' );
    }// this one works properly. It's for removing for admin bar.
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'contributor_posts_action' );
```

Comment: Your never calling the functions so they don't get executed!

Comment: @Rizier123 They are being called with add_action, one works other one doesn't. Also if I add the function remove-menus_contrib() outside the `if condition` along with the add_action that it currently has, it works.

Comment: Where is this `$role` coming from?? Take those functions out of `admin_init` callback, leaving only `add_action`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pulling the `remove_menus_contrib()` and the `add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus_contrib' )` hook function out of your `contributor_posts_action()` function.

Some Wordpress hooks won't work inside other (custom) functions.

Comment: still not working, admin_bar_menu also is only for the admin bar

Comment: OK, Are you sure wordpress is calling admin_menu ?

Comment: I know that admin_menu is a hook so should be called like the rest of the hooks.

Comment: Could you try to remove the `remove_menu_page();` functions from the `remove_menus_contrib();` function and place a `die('success')` in there?

Comment: Nothing happens, function is not getting initialized.

Comment: And it does work if you place it outside of the if statement? (as you're saying in your question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63788/discussion-between-user3467855-and-daniel-gelling).